# What is code (not MAC) in place of IP address?

Tags: ip-address, unknown-host

In place of an IP address, there is a code that looks simular to  "2600:1000:b11c:d167:cb6c:bd27:8c9:41ba". What is this?

Answer (score 2):

`2600:1000:b11c:d167:cb6c:bd27:8c9:41ba` is an example of [IPv6 address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#Address_representation), unlike the 32-bit IPv4 address, its length is 128-bit.

Answer (score 0):

That is a ipv6 address which is basically (Internet Protocol version 6 (IPv6) is the most recent version of the Internet Protocol (IP), the communications protocol that provides an identification and location system for computers on networks and routes traffic across the Internet.) - Google. In place of this would be an ipv4 address. The ipv4 address would look something like this 192.168.1.1,